# Is possible to ignore hover effects on moving cursor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create menus like in Opera or Chrome browser. Is possible  to ignore hover effects on moving cursor,and when cursor stops at certain element's position the hover will work?
 Example of my menu:

http://osiyo-nur.uz/goodgross/
So when i'm hovering to another list element doesn't work properly

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use css rule changing cursor on active elements, like anchors:

```
.menu a {
    cursor: default;
}
```

See fiddle with the effect: https://jsfiddle.net/entio/2cez4rw3/